# How to add unique Item Code every product in open erp

Tags: odoo

I'm adding a new product to the open erp. However, I'm unable to add a unique number to each product. But there should be a unique product number for every product.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [@api.constrains](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#module-openerp.api) decorator.

```
@api.one
@api.constrains('code')
def _unique_code(self):
    if len(self.search([('code', '=', self.code)])) > 1:
        raise ValidationError("Product code must be unique!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Id is the always unique for all model in openerp.

And another way,

you can also add your custome field for unique number usind "_sql_constraints"

```
eg: _sql_constraints = [
    ('seq_uniq', 'unique (item_code)', _("The Item Code must be \
        unique per Stage!"))]
```